# dropdown login menu using only html/css/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, authentication

Hi i'm looking for a dropdown login/menu without the use of any bootstrap-like css or jQuery (due to school not allowing this..).

It has to be relatively small and ideally it would come down when clicking or hovering above the login button on the nav bar.

Much thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) What have you tried? 2) Where is its code?

Comment: Hello, SO is not a 'code this for me' site. Tell us what you tried and we'll gladly help you out.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a drop-down menu which uses HTML/CSS incorporating a hover effect.

Here's an example of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/rhxxyky8/10/

It uses lists in the form of:

```
<div id='dropdown'>
    <ul>
          <li class='detail'><a href='#'><span>Test 1</span></a>
          <ul>
              <li><input type="text" placeholder="Username"></input></li>
              <li><input type="password" placeholder="Password"></input></li>
              <li><input type="submit"></input><input type="reset"></input></li>              
          </ul>
          </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Without any workings or diagram to follow, what you require is quite difficult to replicate.

This is probably one of the most non-complicated methods, but does not include javascript, thus some would argue that it is more efficient if you require these results.

As for how you'd login without SQL or PHP etc, is beyond me at this point.